# Grails hasOne property within same domain class

Tags: java, hibernate, grails, grails-orm

I have a domain class involving cards that I'm working on. Some, but not all cards, have a back face that references another card. Here's what my domain class looks like:

```
package server

class Card {
    // other properties
    static hasOne = [back: card]
    Card backFace

    static constraints = {
        back nullable: true, unique: true
        backFace nullable: true
    }
}
```

When I go to run the application, Grails gives me the following error

> org.hibernate.MappingException: hasOne property [server.Card.back] is not bidirectional. Specify the other side of the relationship!

I've tried adding the following to the class, but it didn't seem to work:

```
static mappedBy = [back: 'backFace']
```

And I also tried flipping `back` and `backFace`, but that didn't work either. What am I doing incorrectly here?

Comment: Do you really intend to have two properties and not just one? If you want to have a `back` that optionally references another card just remove the `Card backFace` property as it's redundant.

Comment: I intended to just have 1 property. should I remove the `mappedBy` line as well? I removed both and still get the same error.

Comment: if you want to be it unidirectional just remove line `static hasOne = [back: card]` and of course it's `constraints` and unnecessary `mappedBy` statement. do not forget to drop table from db before relaunching.

Comment: Well, that seemed to have fixed my problem to an extent. Now it looks like I'm having another problem where MySQL is saying the table doesn't exist: `Caused by: com.mysql.jdbc.exceptions.jdbc4.MySQLSyntaxErrorException: Table 'server.card' doesn't exist` I've got my dev datasource's `dbCreate` set to `create-drop`, so I'm not sure why it's happening. I'll have to check the URL I guess

Comment: Looks like my issue has something to do with MySQL, as using an H2 database seems to work fine. I'll post a new question

Answer (score -1):

### Try it s below

```
class Card {
    ...
    static hasOne = [back: BackFace]
}

class BackFace{
    Card card
}
```

Comment: I don't want to create another domain class to do this. If you can do what I'm trying to do with a `hasMany` as specified in the grails documentation, shouldn't it be possible with a one-to-one relationship?